# expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'extern'

Tags: objective-c, constants

I'm trying to create a class with global constants:

```
//Resources.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Resources : NSObject 
{
extern NSString * const MY_CONST;
}
@end
```

and

```
//Resources.m
#import "Resources.h"

@implementation Resources

NSString * const MY_CONST = @"my constant";

@end
```

And getting this nasty error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'extern'

What do I need to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put

```
extern NSString * const MY_CONST;
```

outside of class interface declaration. `MY_CONST` is not a class member, so why put it inside?

Comment: not so much of an option: it's illegal to put an extern or static variable in an ivar

Comment: Jared P , I didn't get it, what do u mean?